# Pspell не работает

Tags: php, apache

Доброго времени уважаемые коллеги! Помогите пожалуйста с pspell. Я выполнил следующее в консоли:

```
sudo apt-get install libpspell-dev 
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pspell
sudo apt-get install aspell-ru
```

При печати phpinfo() я его вижу как расширение. Набираю в консоли aspell -a  - работает. Но из php кода я его запустить не могу. Вот такой код возвращает мне пустой массив, хотя на хостинге все отрабатывает:

```
function fixMistakeInQString($string, $lang){
    $pspell_config = pspell_config_create($lang);
    pspell_config_mode($pspell_config, PSPELL_FAST);
    $pspell_link = pspell_new_config($pspell_config);

    if (!pspell_check($pspell_link, $string)) {
        $result = pspell_suggest($pspell_link, $string);
        foreach ($result as $key => $value){
            if(preg_match('~\s~ui', $value) || preg_match('~-~ui', $value)){
                unset($result[$key]);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }else{
        return array($string);
    }
}
```

Comment: от куда запускаете код браузер или консоль?

Comment: Запускаю на локальном сервере. Обращаюсь через браузер. Эта функция должна дать мне варианты исправления в поиске на сайте. В консоли мне ее запускать нет смысла.

Comment: значит в php_cli нет модуля